# Matplotlib display the first {n} images from each folder

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have one main folder, and there are 3 sub folders under the main folder. I want to plot the first few images from each sub folder in one single plot. How can I do that?

So far, I am able to perform the two tasks separately:

1. Print the first 5 images from each folder

   ```
   directory=os.listdir('main_folder')
   for each in directory:
       currentFolder = 'main_folder/' + each
       for file in os.listdir(currentFolder)[0:5]:
           fullpath = main_folder+ "/" + file
           print(fullpath)
           img=mpimg.imread(fullpath)
           plt.imshow(img)
           #this seems to be plotting the last image
   ```
2. Plot several subplot on one plot

   ```
   for i in range(1, 7):
       plt.subplot(2, 3, i)
   ```

How can I combine the two, so I can plot the first few images from each folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may directly integrate the second part into the loop, using `enumerate`.

```
directory=os.listdir('main_folder')
for each in directory:
    plt.figure()
    currentFolder = 'main_folder/' + each
    for i, file in enumerate(os.listdir(currentFolder)[0:5]):
        fullpath = main_folder+ "/" + file
        print(fullpath)
        img=mpimg.imread(fullpath)
        plt.subplot(2, 3, i)
        plt.imshow(img)
```

Comment: Thank you! Seems to have gone a bit further with this one - it's plotting the first 5 images from the last subfolder. How can I make it to plot 5 images from each sub folder, not just the last subfolder?

Comment: I updated the answer. This would give you 3 figures, each with 5 subplots. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Perfect. That worked like a charm! Fyi it seems like 'fullpath = main_folder+ "/" + file' should read 'fullpath = currentFolder+ "/" + file'. Thanks so much for your help!